# How to return cell value with For Next loop using 2 sheets and multiple conditions - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm attempting to match values between two sheets and if found and the conditions are met, perform the action of changing the cell colour.

PROBLEM:

I'm getting an error with my `For...Next` loop, even though I thought I have a NEXT for each FOR statement. Not sure what I've done wrong.

Also, I'm not sure my counters are setup correctly to accurately scan through each sheet/column needed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub ReadData()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Ref1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("TRA")
lastrow = Sheets("Ref1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("TRA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Ref1").Activate


i = 2
k = 2


For i = 2 To lastrow
    For k = 2 To lastrow2
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Active" Then
            If ws.Cells(i, 18).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value And (ws2.Cells(i, 23).Value <> "Cancelled" Or ws2.Cells(i, 23).Value <> "Completed") Then
    Cells(i, 20).Interior.ColorIndex = 9

End If
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not qualifying all of your `Cells` objects. I would start there. You declared worksheet variables  ... **use them**

Comment: You are also missing an `End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick Repair

- To better understand the code, it is often preferable to use letters,
  instead of numbers, for columns.

### The Code

```
Sub ReadData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long

    ' Use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook, if the code is
    ' in the same workbook where these sheets are.
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = .Worksheets("Ref1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("TRA")
    End With

    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Active" Then
            For k = 2 To lastrow2
                If ws.Cells(i, "R").Value = ws2.Cells(k, "A").Value _
                        And ws2.Cells(k, "W").Value <> "Cancelled" _
                        And ws2.Cells(k, "W").Value <> "Completed" Then
                    ws.Cells(i, "T").Interior.ColorIndex = 9 ' Brown
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you - this prevented any errors. however, it doesn't seem to be performing the actual condition of colouring the cell in. any idea where the gap lies with regard to that?

i tried changing this line >> If ws.Cells(i, 18).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value _ << and changing i to k here: ws2.cells(k,1).Value and it highlights the first instance where the condition is met. but it doesn't work for any other instances after that.

Comment: i replaced  the i with K in ws2.cells >> "If ws.Cells(i, 18).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value" << and it works. by stepping in, it seems the i is not cycling through to the next row if the value if the condition is met and executes. i tried adding in "NEXT i" but that produces an error.

Comment: @VBAWARD: This should work now. Where you have ws2, you use k, where you have ws use i. Now just check if the columns are alright and that should be it. Notice I have changed For i = i to... and For k = k to... That was a bad idea.

Comment: There's also a logic flaw in the OPs If statement.  `(ws2.Cells(k, "W").Value <> "Cancelled"  Or ws2.Cells(k, "W").Value <> "Completed")` will always be true

Comment: @chris neilsen: Believe it or not, I just thought the same thing, it should be AND. Or the both <> should be =. I'm going with the first solution.

Comment: thanks for that heads up! corrected this and it worked great! if i may ask, what change allowed the i and k variables to cycle through to the next one?

Comment: @VBAWARD: There are 3 k's. You changed 2 for yourself, I just changed the 3rd and changed the OR to AND. There is just another 'tiny' detail, you can safely use **Exit For** after the line containing interior, so when you have found the value, you stop looping. Have changed the code. The looping afterwards would have been in vain, since you might or might not found another match, but the cell is already colored.

Comment: @VBAWARD: The 1st If statement has to be before the 2nd For Next loop, not to be checked for each cell in ws2, since it is already "Active". BTW I liked you using **k** for the row counter of ws2, because in 'my book', **j** is reserved for columns.